# How to import material UI component in main class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So, I'm trying to add a "SimpleAppBar" element to my React app design.
Here the code of this element, directly from Material UI official website:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
};

function SimpleAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
            Photos
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleAppBar);
```

I copy this code to seperate file (*AppBar.js*). Now I'm importing this file to my main file, using *import AppBar from './components/AppBar'*.
And I believe next I need to call SimpleAppBar() function from AppBar.js file in some part of my main class code for rendering app bar itself, but how to do it, how it should look in the code ?
I already tried smth like {new AppBar().SimpleAppBar()}, but failed.
P.S. I am newbie in JavaScript and Material UI, so please don't be angry if it is a stupid question ) Project structure:
**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import ToDo from './ToDo';

ReactDOM.render(<ToDo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Todo.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './ToDo.css';
import ToDoItem from './components/ToDoItem';
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';
import Logo from './assets/logo.png';

const appBar = <AppBar />

class ToDo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [
                {
                    title: 'Cup cleaning',
                    todo: "Wash and take away the Kurzhiy's cup from WC"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Smoking rollton',
                    todo: 'Do some rollton and cigarettes'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Curious dream',
                    todo: 'Build a time machine'
                }
            ],
            title: '',
            todo: ''
        };
    };

    createNewToDoItem = () => {
      this.setState(({ list, title, todo }) => ({
        list: [
            ...list,
          {
            title,  
            todo
          }
        ],
        title: '',
        todo: ''
      }));
    };

    handleKeyPress = e => {
        if (e.target.value !== '') {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.createNewToDoItem();
          }

        }
    };

    handleTitleInput = e => {
      this.setState({
        title: e.target.value,
      });
    };

    handleTodoInput = e => {
        this.setState({
         todo: e.target.value
      });
    };

    deleteItem = indexToDelete => {
        this.setState(({ list }) => ({
          list: list.filter((toDo, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
      }));
    };

    editItem = (i, updTitle, updToDo) => {
        let arr = this.state.list;
        arr[i].title = updTitle;
        arr[i].todo = updToDo;
        this.setState ({list: arr});
    };

    eachToDo = (item, i) => {
        return <ToDoItem
                    key={i}
                    title={item.title}
                    todo={item.todo}
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, i)}
                    editItem={this.editItem.bind(this, i)}
                />
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ToDo">
                <img className="Logo" src={Logo} alt="React logo"/>
                <h1 className="ToDo-Header">{AppBar}</h1>
                <div className="ToDo-Container">

                    <div className="ToDo-Content">
                        {this.state.list.map(this.eachToDo)}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new todo" value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleTodoInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <button className="ToDo-Add" onClick={this.createNewToDoItem}>+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: Don't worry about it being a stupid question. We all started somewhere. Javascript ecosystem can be very overwhelming to start with. I would highly recommend reading the official [docs/guides](https://reactjs.org/docs/) or this [free course on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/courses/the-beginner-s-guide-to-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You don't need to call the function, in react, everything is a [component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). A component can either have [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)(class) or be stateless (functional). To put it simply, stateless components do not have a lifecycle and do not have a `state`. Essentially, it is just the `render` method of a class component, but you cannot read this.state.

So, you would use your export as:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';

// declare a functional component, with es6 shorthand
const myapp = <AppBar />
// assumes that there is a <div id=root></div> somewhere in your index.html
ReactDOM.render(myapp, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: that will indeed help

Comment: dubes, it was just a typo )
I tried to refer to AppBar component inside html, instead of appBar const ))
Now everything seems to work, thank you very much ))

Comment: I posted new question just now, may be you can help )